# Filtering data in R for a column by entries from a different column

Tags: r, excel

I'm trying to organize data as consistent panel data. The only problem is for the two columns  Year and school_id the problem is that a few of the school_id don't have data for all the years. Is there a way where I can filter the dataset where only school_ids with years containing 2012,2013,2014 are included?

I'd prefer to do this in R, but if it could be done in Excel that's fine.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example as well as the desired output.

Comment: re. minimal working example: you can have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make a great reproducible example in R. Furthermore, it would also be helpful if you outline what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start, though I have no clue as to what your actual data looks like (also, try making a search on stackoverflow with `[r] remove na data frame`)

```
 set.seed(422)
 (
 foo <- data.frame(
   school_id = c(0, 10, NA, 8),
   Year = c(2011,2012,2013,2014),
   variable_01 = sample(c(1:4, NA), 4, replace=T),
   variable_02 = sample(c(1:4, NA), 4, replace=T),
   variable_03 = sample(c(1:4, NA), 4, replace=T),
   variable_04 = sample(1:4, 4, replace=T),
   variable_05 = sample(c(1:4, NA), 4, replace=T))
 )  
# school_id Year variable_01 variable_02 variable_03 variable_04 variable_05
#         0 2011           3           1           1           4           4
#        10 2012          NA           3           4           1          NA
#        NA 2013          NA           4          NA           3           3
#         8 2014           3           4           1           3           2

 foo[complete.cases(foo[,3:7]), ]
# school_id Year variable_01 variable_02 variable_03 variable_04 variable_05
#         0 2011           3           1           1           4           4
#         8 2014           3           4           1           3           2
```